# Composer: PHP Fatal error: Out of memory || Setting memory_limit doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

When I'm trying to install a new bundle with composer, I'm always running into this problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1690828800) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/.../composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1690828800) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/.../composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
```

I tried to raise the memory limit in php.ini and started a whole new project with fresh composer. I should have enough memory on my machine.

**Update:**

When encountering this problem, also bear in mind that if you change parameters in your PHP.ini, that you've to change them for your PHP CLI. I often forgot that and just changed the php.ini for the version my apache is using...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49994946/1334383

Answer (score 6):

try
    `composer clear-cache`
before
    `composer update`

Answer (score 3):

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` to update composer..

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` fixed the problem for me while updating/installing packages using composer

Answer (score 2):

This command solved my problem.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Answer (score 1):

How you test Memory_limit ?

did you restart Apache?

please do the following steps:

with Xampp in Windows 10

just search this phrase: **memory_limit**

```
;memory_limit=512M
```

by commenting this configuration, in php.ini to:

```
memory_limit =-1
```

then restart the Apache by xampp

[image]

the result is:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit =-1
;memory_limit=512M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `php -d memory_limit=-1 /path/to/composer ...` like [explained in the doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors).

Comment: already did that. Did it in the php.ini file as well as with the parameters. There's no othe result

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. My solution was to update the self composer

`$ php composer.phar self-update`

Comment: Did this as well. Was not helping :( Switched now from a windows machine to linux. No troubles anymore

Comment: Could not open input file: composer.phar THIS error appeared when i type it in my command line in windows

Answer (score 0):

in **windows** i used this commands:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 C:\composer\composer.phar install
```

and

```
php C:\composer\composer.phar self-update
```

> Updating to version 1.10.10 (stable channel).
> Downloading (100%)

> Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.10.7

Answer (score 0):

Run `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install` instead of `composer install`. It worked for me.