# Composer update show this error: VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008]

Tags: composer-php

Composer worked find yesterday, but today after I trying install:
composer require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"

While run composer update command it show me error:

> VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] VirtualAlloc() failed:
> [0x00000008] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 956301312)
> (tried to allocate 201326600 bytes) in
> phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php
> on line 84
>
> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 956301312) (tried to allocate
> 201326600 bytes) in
> phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php
> on line 84

I try update composer on my other projects, it is worked fine. After some researching I increased memory_limit: 4096M(also -1) in php.ini file. Then I tried to increase virtual memory in Computer->Properties, but still show error.

I try to run next command:
composer update -vvv --profile, result in attached image
[Composer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPjL.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of composer do you use?

Comment: Composer version 1.9.1

Comment: Or just stop abusing RAM, just in case, for me it was a Virtual Machine that was eating all my memory and no matter how much config I throw at PHP it never let me run anything until I close everything and run just the clean composer and php artisan commands that I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using 32bit PHP. This version cannot allocate enough memory for composer even if you change the memory_limit to -1 (unlimited).

Please use 64 bit PHP with the Composer to get rid of these memory problems.

Comment: I can't change version. Is there any patch available?

Comment: I don't think there will be patch for this. It's technical limit of 32bit application.

Comment: Under Windows this is it, specialy when under 64 and the default download is for 32bit...